# How to access a user control from a View Model in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP in which i have a user control defined in file1.xaml

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid x:Name="A">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DemoStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="State1"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="State2">
                <Storyboard
                    x:Name="StoryboardDemo"
                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="DemoStateChange"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SomeProperty)">
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid x:Name="StoryboardDemo">
         <Image
            Source="//assets//Image1.jpg"/>
         <Image
            Source="//assets//Image2.jpg"/>
 </UserControl>
```

I am using this usercontrol inside another xaml file file2.xaml

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <control:file1/>
   <ToggleSwitch
        Grid.Row="1"
        Toggled="{x:Bind ViewModel.ChangeImage}"/>
 </Grid>
```

If the user toggles the toggleswitch in on the storyboard should go to state2 and if its off it should go to state1.I am trying to control this storyboard through the view model

File2ViewModel.cs

```
    public void ChangleImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSwitch toggleSwitch = sender as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSwitch;
        if (toggleSwitch != null)
        {
            if (toggleSwitch.IsOn == true)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(file1 , "state2", false); //get an error for the first parameter
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(file1, "state1", false);//get an error for the first parameter
            }
        }
```

How do I trigger the user control to start the storyboard from the ViewModel? Also if the toggle is switched I would like to send a value to manipulate "someproperty" back to the user control so that it can manipulate the view based on that , is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: `file1` is the class name, not the control object that you created in the Xaml code. You could give the usercontrol a name like `<local:file1 x:Name="MyControl1"/>`. Then call the method like `VisualStateManager.GoToState(MyControl1, "state2", false);`

Comment: I tried accessing "Control1" but still get errors in VisualStateManager saying context not found. I have something like this <control:file1 x:Name="MyControl1"/> and VisualStateManager.GoToState(MyControl1, "state2", false);

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your code. You are putting the `ChangleImage method` in the ViewModel. You could set a property in the `File2ViewModel` and assign the control to that property.

I made a simple demo based on your scenario

File2ViewModel:

```
 public class File2ViewModel
{
    public file1 thefile { get; set; }

    public File2ViewModel(file1 file)
    {
        thefile = file;
    }

    public void ChangleImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSwitch toggleSwitch = sender as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSwitch;
        if (toggleSwitch != null)
        {
            if (toggleSwitch.IsOn == true)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(thefile, "state2", false); //get an error for the first parameter
                Debug.WriteLine("test");
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(thefile, "state1", false);//get an error for the first parameter
                Debug.WriteLine("test");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

In the file2 code behind:

```
 public File2ViewModel viewModel { get; set; }
 viewModel = new File2ViewModel(MyControl1);
```

`MyControl1` is the file1 control that you added to the file2 xaml.